# Confused about different implementations of GetHashCode() for short and ushort

Tags: .net, hashcode, primitive-types

Consider the following code:

```
private static void TestHashCode<T>()
{
    dynamic initialValue = 10;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", typeof(T).Name, ((T)initialValue).GetHashCode());
}

TestHashCode<int>();
TestHashCode<uint>();
TestHashCode<long>();
TestHashCode<ulong>();
TestHashCode<short>();
TestHashCode<ushort>();
```

Output:

```
Int32: 10
UInt32: 10
Int64: 10
UInt64: 10
Int16: 655370
UInt16: 10
```

See the difference between `short` and `ushort`? Indeed, the source code is different for these classes:

```
// ushort
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return (int) this;
}

// short
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return (int) (ushort) this | (int) this << 16;
}
```

But at the same time, `GetHashCode()` implementations for signed/unsigned versions of `int` and `long` are equal:

```
// int and uint
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return (int) this;
}

// long and ulong
public override int GetHashCode()
{
  return (int) this ^ (int) (this >> 32);
}
```

Could you please explain why there is a difference between `short` and `ushort` implementations of `GetHashCode()`?

Comment: Perhaps somebody has forgotten to do the same implementation for the unsigned short?..

Comment: I find your question interesting, but there's no reason why the two implementation should be the same, or why they should be different. It's just "an implementation that works". There's no constraint stating that hashcode for signed/unsigned should be the same. In particular. This implementation is made in such a way that a short and a non-zero ushort can never have the same hash. This cannot be done for ints and longs, because they are at least as large as the hash.

Comment: FWIW, `sbyte` seems to have the same kind of implementation as `short`.

Comment: This was written a very, very long time ago on a very early version of the CLR that looked a lot different from the one we know today.  The people that worked on this don't post here, you can only get guesses.  Not what we're trying to do here.

Answer (score -1):

in ushort GetHashCode(), when this = 10;

"return (int) (ushort) this | (int) this << 16;"

yields 0x0000000a | 0x000a0000 => 0x000a000a = 655370

in long and ulong
" return (int) this ^ (int) (this >> 32);"
yields 0x0000000a xor 0x00000000 ==> 0x0000000a = 10;

so I guess one of "GetHashCode" has wrong implementation.